# How to automate development machine for MVC IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis, automation

I don't know if this is entirely possible as a one click and done option, but what I would like is to automate our IIS MVC development setup for new developers.

Basically, what I am looking for is:

- App pool creation if one is not already created (and make sure it is the correct version of .NET 4.0)
- Creation of an IIS Application under the above app pool that points to the source code
- Figure out if `aspnet_regiis -i` is needed (in the case that IIS was installed before 4.0 code was introduced)

I am not looking for a publish option as that does not point to the source code. Also, I am not looking to use the built in VS host as I am trying to use IIS to make sure everything is set up appropriately. Maybe I should not impose these limits and do not need to worry about setting up the machine as described? But if this does sound correct, currently I am looking for a way to set this up straight out of source control? Is that possible, or do I need to have an initial setup phase for all new developers?

Comment: Doesn't VS prompt the user that it's going to create a virtual directory if the project is configured to run in IIS but no such virtual directory exists? I seem to remember this happening to me.

Comment: @spender You are right, I had forgot that you can specify to not use the Visual Studio Development Web Server in the project settings. I just tried this and it solved my problem (I am not sure if it would have solved the need for aspnet_regiis -, but I will have to wait to test that out on a different machine) If you write that up as an answer, I will accept

Comment: @spender Although, I just tried changing the port via localhost:82 and it did not autocreate successfully. Any ideas on that? This was not part of my original question, and not major, so I will still accept if you cannot answer that specifically

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. What you appear to be asking is exactly what IIS Express was designed for. Step 1) Install IIS Express alongside VS on any development machine. Step 2) Set the MVC project to use IIS Express. From that point on, opening said project on any computer with IIS Express installed (and the app config does not match) will result in VS prompting you to add the necessary IIS Express config.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't yet write exactly what you want, Powershell will do what you want.  Here's a tutorial for creating web sites and app pools.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/

Comment: Yah, I just was trying to avoid powershell for this. That would probably be my second option after @spender's

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is setting up the full environment on a computer then making a boot disk to return to that environment. Then run that boot disk on another computer (note: must be of the same type) which you want the environment to be on.

If it must work for different computers, and different operating systems, then the complexity of allowing for the environment to all be done at once will become greater than just doing it yourself unless you are setting up environments as frequently as daily. If that is the case, then perhaps you could make a custom installation program to do that which I am not very familiar with off the top of my head.